Connectivity degree of the complete graph $K_{n}$ is $n-1$
I am doing some exercises to get better at proving graph related statements.

For context, here are the definitions:
Definition:
A graph $G$ is called $ k$-connected, if
1.$ |V(G)|$>k and
2. for every subset $T \subseteq V(G)$ with $|T|<k$, the subgraph $V(G)\setminus T$ is connected.
Let $G$ be a connected graph. We say $G$ has connectivity degree of $k$ if $k$ is the largest $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G$ is $k$-connected or if $V(G)=1$. In the later case we say $G$ has connectivity degree of $0$.

Exercise:
Show that the connectivity degree of the complete graph $K_{n}$ is $n-1$.

Approach:
Visually this statement is obvious, but I am not sure how to write it down and would like some feedback on this.
Let $G(V,E)$ be the complete graph $K_n$, i.e. for every $v_i,v_j \in V $,$i \neq j$, the edges $\{v_i,v_j\} \in E$.
To prove the exercise, we need to consider (all) subsets $T \subseteq V(G)$ with $|T|<n-1$ an show that the induced graph $V(G) \setminus T$ is (still) connected.
In this special case, $G$ is the complete graph thus by "symmetry" we only need to consider one subset $T$, with $|T|=n-2$.
So let $T \subseteq V(G)$ be arbitrary and $|T|=n-2$.
Let $S(V_1,E_1)$ denote the subgraph induced by $V(G) \setminus T$.
By cardinality we know $|V_1(S)|=2$. Let us denote those two vertices by $v_1,v_2$. Since $G$ was complete, $\{v_1,v_2\} \in E_1(S)$. Thus $S(V_1,E_1)$ is connected.
Next we need to show that $|T|=n-2$ really is "maximal".
This would mean considering $|T|=n-1$ and showing that $V(G) \setminus T$ is disconnected.
I have a few questions:
Question 1:
Is my proof alright? Because I have some doubts. Since if we choose $T$ such that $|T|=n-1$, then $V(G) \setminus T$ is just a single vertex. Now I am not sure if a single vertex counts as a connected graph.
Question 2:
For a graph to be $k$-connected we need to check every $T \subset V(G)$ with $|T|<k$.
I don't understand why we have to consider every subset with $|T|<k$. Is there a reason we don't consider all subsets $T$ with $|T|=k-1$?
Question 3:
This exercise was easy because of the symmetry of the complete graph.
In the case of an arbitrary graph, how do I show the "maximality" condition (largest $k$ s.t. ...)? It seems to me that in this case one would have to calculate every combination.

You're overthinking it, for any graph $G$ define $G_p={{p,v}:v\in V(G)\setminus{p}}$ now ${G_v:v\in V(G)}$ is the set of minimal cuts of $G$ iff $G$ is complete whereas we have $\forall v\in V(G)[|G_p|=|V(G)|-1]$, by definition.

I am not understanding your idea. By what you wrote $G_p$ would be the set of all edges ${p,v}$ for $v \in V(G) \setminus {p}$, i.e. all edges we loose when we remove the vertex $p$.  By ${G_p : p \in V(G)} $ we are considering the collection of those $G_p$. What do you mean by  "${G_p : p \in V(G)} $ is the set of minimal cuts of $G$"?  I do get though that $\forall v \in V(G) : |G_v|=|V(G)|-1$.
